# Starship deceleration during belly flop?

Tags: spacex, landing, reuse, spacex-starship

Was just wondering what level of deceleration did they get during that belly flop manouver?

**Updated:**
Hiya, you're all correct, and I was a tad vague in my question!  What I'm after is the vertical deceleration experienced by SN8 after it assumed the belly-flop position and prior to the 'flip'.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you refer to vertical delta-V, since there's an increase in lateral speed :-)

Comment: Hi and welcome, could you add details about what you mean by "manouver", and are you talking about SN8 flight test, or future Starship entering Earth's atmosphere from orbital speed and altitude?

Comment: @qqjkztd well, seeing as the OP used the past tense, it's pretty safe to conclude he's referring to SN8 :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft you're right. I guess since there's no data publically available (only telemetry simulations) One bold prediction could be : Once terminal velocity is reached, SN8 experiences slightly more than 1g, along atmospheric density increase, and therefore drag, until landing burn flip.

Answer (score -6):

By definition, less than 1G since it continued to fall.

That constrains the possible set of values.

Comment: Not true, let alone not useful.   You can decelerate at a 100G rate for a millisecond and "continue to fall"